# How to create time attribute in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I tried to create a table this way:

```
create table attendance (
      userId char(10) primary key not null, 
      name varchar(35) not null, 
      date_attendance date not null, 
      start_time timestamp 'HH24:MI:SS', 
      finish_time timestamp 'HH24:MI:SS'
);
```

Am I right about creating the time fields this way or there is some better option?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: create table attendance (userId char(10) primary key not null, name varchar(35) not null, date_attendance date not null, start_time timestamp 'HH24:MI:SS', start_time timestamp 'HH24:MI:SS');


I want to know whether this is right or not?

Comment: @AgusMaloco, I just realized when I was formatting your question for you. Do you know you have two fields with same name?

Comment: create table attendance (userId char(10) primary key not null, name varchar(35) not null, date_attendance date not null, start_time timestamp 'HH24:MI:SS', finish_time timestamp 'HH24:MI:SS');



I mean another one is finish_time as changed above.
so is this right or i need to change something?

Comment: @AgusMaloco, You should be making that correction in your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Timestamp` will hold both date and time. There is data type [`time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) as well, which might be better suited for your use case.

```
CREATE TABLE attendance (
      userId char(10) primary key not null, 
      name varchar(35) not null, 
      date_attendance date not null, 
      start_time time,
      finish_time time
);
```

Comment: create table attendance (userId char(10) primary key not null, name varchar(35) not null, date_attendance date not null, start_time time 'HH24:MI:SS', finish_time time 'HH24:MI:SS');


so, you mean like above?
I've changed that.

Comment: @AgusMaloco, Type `time` will automatically have `HH:MM:SS` specified.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty right and one thing you can do is while providing a date set to not null you can also provide a default date to it by assigning getDate or getUTcDate() functions to them(depending on the app requirement)

Answer (score 0):

What is the `HH24:MM:SS`?  That looks like an Oracle/Postgres argument to the `TO_CHAR()` function.

Presumably, you want two different *times*, and MySQL has a data type for that:

```
create table attendance (
      userId char(10) primary key not null, 
      name varchar(35) not null, 
      date_attendance date not null, 
      start_time time, 
      end_time time
);
```

You are confusing `timestamp` and `time`.  You use `timestamp` when you want to include time zone information in the column values.  I am guessing that timezone information is not important for your application.

This imposes the strict requirement that each `attendance` record is on a single day.  An alternative is just to use `datetime` for both:

```
create table attendance (
      userId char(10) primary key not null, 
      name varchar(35) not null, 
      start_time datetime, 
      end_time datetime
);
```

This would allow the `end_time` to pass midnight -- something that might be useful at some point.

In addition, I would recommend using an auto-incremented integer for the primary key:

```
create table attendance (
      userId unsigned auto_increment primary key,
      name varchar(35) not null, 
      start_time datetime, 
      end_time datetime
);
```

Finally, when you want to format a date/time/datetime as a string, use `date_format()`.